# chisquare vector different length

Tags: matlab, chi-squared

I have 3 data vectors representing the gender (0=male, 1=female) of 3 groups A,B,C.

for example

```
A = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];
B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0];
C = [1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1];
```

and relative number of male and female

```
n_maleA =6;
n_femaleA =4;
n_maleB = 1;
n_femaleB = 7;
n_maleC = 4;
n_femaleC = 9;
```

I would like to know if there are significant differences in gender between the 3 groups.
To do this I read that is possible to use

```
   [tbl,chi2stat,pval] = crosstab(x1,x2)
```

How can I use this with more than 2 groups of data and with data that have different length?
Is there any other way to perform the chi-squared test in matlab that suits with my case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not how a chi2-square works I'm afraid. You'll have to reduce your information to the fraction of e.g. female genders in each group. These fractions combined with their uncertainties could then be compared in a chi2-manner.

Comment: mmm I thought that it would be given by the crosstab automatically since x1 and x2 should be raw data...anyway I edited the question with the info you needed.. can you please give me an example of how to use the chi2-square? thanks